# Lucene.Net Indexwriter clarification

Tags: c#, lucene.net

What is the difference between

```
var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer,true,IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
```

AND

```
var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(LuceneDirectory,Lucene_analyzer,IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
```

Thanks
R

Comment: COnsidered putting more than 10 seconds into trying like to - ah - read the documentation? Or shall we do your work?

Comment: @TomTom, FYI I did read the documentation before posting the question. You don't have to be sarcastic.

Comment: Documentation says, Constructs an IndexWriter for the index in d. Text will be analyzed with a. If create is true, then a new, empty index will be created in d, replacing the index already there, if any. 2) Constructs an IndexWriter for the index in d, first creating it if it does not already exist.  Does that mean that if I use 2nd one that Index is overwritten or newly created?? I dont comprehend this properly